# Regex Regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex

We have implemented the invocation of brill tagger from our c# code. We just neede to know what is the correct Regex regular expression for eliminating all from a string, but jst keep a-z,A-Z, full stop and comma. We tried `[^a-zA-Z\.\,]` on the online regular expression tester and it is giving the correct result, but when implemented in C#, it is not working properly. We also tried several other combinations but we are not getting the correct result.

This is the format in which we are writing:

```
strFileContent = Regex.Replace(strFileContent, @"[^a-zA-Z\.\,]", "");
```

but we are not getting the desired output. what is wrong??

Comment: It isn't by chance the unescaped period?

Comment: The problem isn't with your regex. What do you mean by "it is not working properly"??

Comment: I like how the problem has been edited out and now everyone is wondering what is going on. The above Regex works, it was previously broken.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Replace(yourString, @"[^a-z\.\,]", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

**EDIT:** I can't see anything wrong with what you are doing, my answer is exactly the same. I tested both in LINQPad and they both return the same result.

Comment: I have that exact same Regex in my application and it's working flawlessly. It should be working! :/